# Access denied when connecting to mongosqld with MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB using MySQL through mongosqld. I have mongosqld running with a config file that looks like

```
security:
  enabled: true
mongodb:
  net:
    uri: test-db
    auth:
      username: usertest
      password: pass
      source: admin
schema:
    path: schema.drdl
```

I have it hosted on a [mongo ODBC manager](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-odbc-driver/releases/) with `SERVER=127.0.0.1`, `PORT=3071`, `DATABASE=test_db`, `UID=usertest?source=admin`, `PWD=pass`. I am able to connect to and query this MongoDB through Excel using [Mongo's tutorial for that](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/connect/excel/), but I am not able to do the same with MySQL using [Mongo's tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/connect/mysql/). When I try to connect from terminal with `mysql 'user=usertest?source=admin' --default-auth=mongosql_auth -p` I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'usertest' and`handshake error: unable to saslStart conversation 0: Authentication failed.` from the mongosqld side. I am doing this on macOS. What could be causing this problem only for trying to connect from MySQL?

Comment: What is MySQL version(x,y,z)?

Comment: mysql ver 8.0.12

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [Connect from the MySQL Client](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/connect/mysql/) You can use the command-line MySQL client to connect to the MongoDB Connector for BI.

**Connect from MySQL without Authentication or TLS/SSL**

To connect to a mongosqld instance listening on the MySQL default port 3307, run the following command:

```
mysql --protocol tcp --port 3307
```

**Connect from MySQL with Authentication**

Install the C Authentication Plugin as described in Install the [C Authentication Plugin](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/install-auth-plugin-c/).

The following example uses the C authentication plugin to connect to a [mongosqld](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#bin.mongosqld) instance listening on **`port 3307`** as user reportsUser. The MySQL shell prompts for the password after the command has been entered.

```
mysql --user='reportsUser?source=admin' --default-auth=mongosql_auth -p
```

Note: This example assumes that the authentication plugin file mongosql_auth.so is located in the default MySQL plugin folder. The location of the plugin folder varies by platform, but you can locate it by running the following command:

```
mysql_config --plugindir
```

`mysql_config.pl` can find the plugin directory only on macOS and Linux hosts.

**Important :** The C Authentication plugin was developed against `MySQL 5.7.18` Community Edition (64-bit), and tested with `MySQL 5.7.18` Community Edition and the latest version of MongoDB Connector for BI. The plugin is not compatible with MySQL Server or Connector/ODBC driver version 8 and later.

**Connect from MySQL with Authentication and TLS/SSL**

To connect to a [mongosqld](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#bin.mongosqld) instance listening on port 3307, as user grace using authentication mechanism PLAIN, and using specific TLS/SSL CA and x.509 certificates, run the following command:

```
mysql --enable-cleartext-plugin --protocol tcp --port 3307 \
  --user='grace?mechanism=PLAIN&source=$external' \
  --ssl-ca=/path_to_the_CAcert/ca.crt \
  --ssl-key=/path_to_my_certificate_key/mysql.key \
  --ssl-cert=/path_to_my_client_certificate/mysql.crt \
  -p
```

**Important:** The [binary distribution of MySQL Community](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ssl-libraries.html) uses the [yaSSL](https://www.wolfssl.com/products/yassl/) SSL library to encrypt connections. MySQL Enterprise uses [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) which is compatible with MongoDB Connector for BI. Use MySQL Enterprise to connect to BI Connector over TLS / SSL.

If using the `$external authentication` source, wrap your username in single quotes or escape the $ character with a backslash to prevent your shell from performing interpolation.

For further your reference [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/auth-plugin-c-mysql-options/#mysql-command-options)

Comment: I said in my question that I already went through that tutorial and it did not work.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark, Is it mysql ver 8.0.12 community edition or else?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark, Make sure that as per MongoDB documentation , the required port of MySQL Server .

Comment: I figured it out, i was because I was on the wrong version of mysql.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark, As initially i have reminded to MySQL Version as well as specific port . That's why again write down the MongoDB documentation with some important highlighted word.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was just the version of MySQL that I was using that was the problem. I was using MySQL version 8.0.12, but the documentation says

```
The C Authentication plugin was developed against MySQL 5.7.18 
Community Edition (64-bit), and tested with MySQL 5.7.18 Community 
Edition and the latest version of MongoDB Connector for BI. The 
plugin is not compatible with MySQL Server or Connector/ODBC driver 
version 8 and later.
```

Once I downloaded and used MySQL version 5.7, I was able to connect successfully.

Comment: I have already highlighted the MySQL version (5.7.18 ) in my answer.